# Iframe to Main URL

Tags: php, html, iframe

As of my requirement, I have placed an anchor tag in an `IFRAME`. When I click on anchor link, the page redirects the page in the `IFRAME`. Here, my requirement is when user clicks on anchor tag, (Which is in `IFRAME`) the page redirects to the main url (Not in the `IFRAME`). How can I do this in PHP or in JavaScript. Can you please say some thing?

Comment: Do you wanna click on a link on `iframe` and it should change the whole page or what?

Answer (score 0):

try `<iframe> <a href="#" onclick='window.location.href="homepage.php"' >click here </a>  </iframe>`??..  this ones javasript..

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for the [`<a target=`](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp) attribute. Setting it to `_top` will change the url of the outermost frame, and setting it to `_parent` will change the url of the parent frame.